# Objective-C Protocol Conformance Using Subclass in Method Signature

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm probably missing something here as this seems like a pretty basic Objective-C question, but not finding any similar questions (maybe I'm searching the wrong thing, sorry in advance if so!). My question is around enforcing a class that conforms to a protocol to have the correct type in it's method signatures. Since that doesn't seem to be enforced by the compiler, what's the best practice here.

Let me provide an example.

```
// View.h

@protocol View <NSObject>

- (void)createNewViewUsing:(UIView *)view;

@end

// SomeView.h

@interface SomeView : NSObject <View>

@end

- (void)createNewViewUsing:(UIStackView *)view {
    NSLog(@"The view is %@", view);
    NSLog(@"%@", view.arrangedSubviews); // CRASH!
}

// Implementation

SomeView *const view = [[SomeView alloc] init];
UIView *const anotherView = [[UIView alloc] init];
[view createNewViewUsing:anotherView];
```

How do I avoid this crash? Is the correct thing to do to just make sure I'm always matching the method signature as my protocol and then check the type? How do I ensure someone else (or my future self) does this? Why does the compiler not enforce this?

Comment: Because Objective C is C, so it happily lets you shoot yourself in the foot. There is an option you can select when you create a new project that lets you avoid these type of problems "Language: Swift" 

Comment: @Paulw11 is right, but it's not because it's C (since protocols aren't part of C). It's because it's ObjC. But his point is totally right. This just isn't something the compiler enforces. Would it be helpful? Absolutely. But it doesn't. Why? Because they didn't implement that. Could they? Yeah. Will they? Probably not. Protocols in ObjC have a long history of being "advisory."

Comment: Yeah, I guess what I meant is that objective c  followed the ethos of C where it favours performance (and compilation speed) over protecting you from yourself. We can see where they have added some features like null ability indications and lightweight generics for `NSArray` to try and make the language a bit safer, but it will never be Swift

Comment: That is freedom, not weakness ... with great freedom comes great responsibility ...

Answer (score 1):

In Objective-C you have to keep track of it yourself. So you are totally allowed to do

```
- (void)createNewViewUsing:(UIStackView *)view
```

with the understanding that you will then only message this with stackviews and not with views. If you deviate from this you do so at your own risk.

However, a better approach is to stick to the original protocol with something as below

```
- (void)createNewViewUsing:(UIView *)view {
    if ( [view isKindOfClass:UIStackView.class] )
    {
        // Cast it
        UIStackView * sv = view;

        // Now you are safe ... use sv in what follows
    }
    else // ... not a stackview ... maybe pass to parent class
```

This of course adds a lot of overhead to your code but you may totally need it for e.g. a large project. You are the one making the judgement call here.

Comment: I was just wondering how to protect for this if, let's say, I have this protocol in a library. Technically my library code is sending a message to this sector and causing a crash, but I guess it's still on the consumer since the implementation is incorrect. Just tested what happens with a protocol from UIKit and same issue (e.g. using a custom subclass in the `textViewDidChange:` delegate). So if Apple doesn't protect against this I guess there's really nothing that can be done. I guess checking that selectors conforming to protocols have the same type is good to look for in code reviews?

Comment: It depends ... if you have real tight code and you have a function that *always* will be messaged with say a ```UIView``` then it makes sense to NOT check - it is just overkill. On the other hand, if you have some general function and/or a big team and this function gets called a lot and *especially* if it has been called in the past with wrong args then you can use it as extra protection. Or you can add the check in DEBUG mode as a compromise. Also, as you point out, this check is the responsibility of the implementation not the caller, but at the same time the caller *should* call correctly.